# Centered header with scrartcl KOMA-Script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I would like to create a simple header in an `scrartcl` (KOMA-Script) class document which contains left aligned, centered and right aligned parts. I read that I am supposed to use the package `scrlayer-scrpage` with `scrartcl`, however as far as I can see it only uses `\ihead`/`\ohead` (inner and outer) headers.

Which package should I use with `scrartcl` class document to design my header?

Comment: `scrlayer-scrpage` provides also `\chead` and for two sided documents `\lehead` (left even), `\rehead` (right even), `\lohead` (left odd) and `\rohead` (right odd) and `\cehead` and `\cohead`. For more information see the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scrlayer-scrpage provides also `\chead` and for two sided documents `\lehead` (left even), `\rehead` (right even), `\lohead` (left odd) and `\rohead` (right odd) and `\cehead` and `\cohead`. For more information see the documentation.

Copy from the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf):

[image]